# Expletive it: reference to they/them

Tags: grammatical-number, formality, case, dummy-pronouns, extraposition

Which of these is used correctly?

1. It were them.
2. It was them.
3. It was they.
4. It were they.

I actually think the "it" is an expletive indicator so noun is whether *them* or *they* and since both are plural, the correct one should be 1 or 4. Is that right?

Comment: A syntactic expletive by definition contributes nothing to the sentence's meaning. Sentences 1 and 4 of your examples are not valid English because "it" is singular (in these cases, implicitly acting as a pronoun representing an agent responsible for an act). Therefore the word "it" contributes meaning to the sentence. A better example of the syntactic expletive is found in the statement, "It will rain tomorrow." In this example, "it" has no meaning.

Comment: I expect there are still one or two people left who would argue that the copula should take the nominative, and use 'It was they'. Everyone else will ignore them and use 'It was them.'

Comment: Yeah, I have stumbled upon some sources that say it should be "they" nevertheless it would not be important in colloquial speech but one should consider the variations of grammar in very formal or legal documents I guess.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Haha, that sounds about right to me. They are actually both correct depending on context, though, as "nominative" isn't really the right way to view the form. Instead, consider the difference as subjective as opposed to objective. While both are appropriate for that very simple sentence structure, the difference in meaning between the two is *vast*--a feature which, by and large, is ignored by the English speaking demographic at large, many of whom will use whichever they darn well please as though the two are perfectly interchangeable.

Comment: Except in a very limited context (like as a short answer to a long question), all of those sentences are ungrammatical. Dummy _it_ does not occur by itself. It is always a part of a construction -- [Extraposition](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+extraposition+dummy+it) in this case -- that involves several constituents of the sentence, and makes no sense outside that construction.

Comment: As I said in my first comment, the word "it" serves a purpose in these example sentences, each of which is no doubt anything more than a short answer to a question. The nature of the sentence, though, is irrelevant to its correctness. The word "it" is neither a syntactic expletive nor an example of extraposition *in these specific examples*. I even went so far to give an example of use of "it" as a genuine syntactic expletive--which, to work, uses also extraposition.

Comment: You never say "it were" in the nominative case.  It's always "it was".  Don't be confused by the fact that *they were*; the verb has to agree with the subject, which is *it*.

Answer (score 1):

If the subject is the action then It was done by them, as in 2. It was them.

If the subject is the actor then It was they who did it, as in 3. It was they.

If the action took place in a remote part of Yorkshire then either way, it might be acceptable to use It were them.

Answer (score 0):

From my comment on the question itself:

A syntactic expletive by definition contributes nothing to the sentence's meaning. Sentences 1 and 4 of your examples are not valid English because "it" is singular (in these cases, implicitly acting as a pronoun representing an agent responsible for an act). Therefore the word "it" contributes meaning to the sentence. A better example of the syntactic expletive is found in the statement, "It will rain tomorrow." In this example, "it" has no meaning.

Edited for an answer format:

Sentences 1 and 4 of your examples are not valid English because "it" is singular (in these cases, implicitly acting as a pronoun representing an agent responsible for an act).

That said, "syntactic expletive" by definition means the expletive contributes no meaning to the sentence overall. In these cases, the word "it" presumably acts as a pronoun representing an agent responsible for an act, if the context of the example can be inferred to be a response to a question asking who or what did something. For the sentences in question, then, the word "it" contributes necessary meaning and is not an example of syntactic expletive.

Answer (score -2):

In a comment on the question, John Lawler answered:

> Except in a very limited context (like as a short answer to a long question), all of those sentences are ungrammatical. Dummy *it* does not occur by itself. It is always a part of a construction — [Extraposition](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+extraposition+dummy+it) in this case —  that involves several constituents of the sentence, and makes no sense outside that construction.

Comment: This is not an example of use of "dummy it" (i.e., syntactic expletive). The word "it" serves a purpose in each of the given examples (or those which are otherwise grammatically correct, anyway), markedly different from true examples of syntactic expletive, such as, "It was not nice for him to steal the child's candy." Note that this sentence can be rewritten with use of "it", as, "For him to steal the child's candy was not nice," well illustrating the argument that the word "it" serves no purpose here.